# Rails 5 / Devise - delete users as admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise to manage authentication. I have a `User` model and `Admin` model. I want to be able to allow both users and admins soft delete user accounts.

I have implemented the soft delete for users and everything works well, however, adding functionality for admins results in a `401 unauthorized` and a redirect to the user sign in page. I'm not exactly sure how to get around this.

So far I have:

#### config/routes.rb

```
...
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  resources :users, only: [:destroy], controller: 'members/registrations', as: :user_registration do
    get 'cancel'
  end
end
...
```

#### controllers/members/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    not_authorized unless authorized?
    @user.soft_delete
    user_post_destroy if is_current_user?
  end

  private

  def authorized?
    if signed_in?
      is_current_user?
    else
      session[:session_id] == @user.author_session_token
    end
  end

  def not_authorized
    flash[:error] = t('errors.messages.not_authorized')
    flash.keep
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end

  def user_post_destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

  def is_current_user?
    @user == current_user
  end

end
```

#### models/user.rb

```
...
def soft_delete
  update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
end

def active_for_authentication?
  super && !deleted_at
end

def inactive_message
  !deleted_at ? super : :deleted_account
end
...
```